# Lenovo Battery 95% to 5%

Tags: ubuntu, battery, lenovo-laptop

So a couple of days ago I was using my lenovo laptop (ThinkPad P14s Gen2) and I was quite surprised at the battery usage. I noticed it was at 95% battery charge. Then maybe an half hour later, I noticed it was at 97% percent. So I was quite happy with the laptop battery saving features (especially since I was using it for several hours).

Next day, I did the same thing. I was using the laptop for only an hour at most when I was shown a critical message that the laptop was at 5% battery.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufi9V.png) is the screenshot from the "Power Statistics" battery usage history.

Any idea what is going on with my lenovo?

Comment: How old is the battery edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: My own personal experience with Lenovo (I had a Yoga 510) is that their batteries are of *extremely* poor quality. In the end, the battery could only last about 20 minutes before running completely flat. The Lenovo power manager said that the battery could also only hold 30% of its original capacity. If your processor isn't running at 100% all the time and you can't narrow down what program is using all that power, your battery needs replacing. I would recommend getting it from somewhere other than Lenovo.

Comment: The laptop is 2 months old at most so I figured it should have no battery issues.